# why tailwind does not allow styling direct children using *: modifier to work with styling children directly

Tags: css, frontend, tailwind-css

I sometimes run into situations when styling elements where most of them use the same styles, except for one or two unique elements.

I guess i want the *: modifier to work with styling children directly and adding custom styles for unique elements .

for example :

```
        <div className="flex min-h-[300px] w-[800px] flex-col gap-7 rounded-3xl bg-[#EFEEEF] p-5 py-6 *:bg-white">
          <div className="flex w-full items-center justify-between gap-2">
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col gap-8 rounded-3xl border p-4">
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col gap-8 rounded-3xl border p-4">
          </div>
          <div className="flex flex-col gap-8 rounded-3xl border p-4">
          </div>
          <div className="flex h-10 gap-3 self-end">
          </div>
        </div>
```

Now, I want *:bg-white to apply to all children except for the first and last elements. If there's a better alternative, I would really like to know. Thanks.

I checked the docs , tried bg-none.

Answer (score 1):

Tailwind allows you to add [arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants), which we can use to select all children elements that are not the first or last child. While Tailwind hasn't added a `not:` modifier, we can still use the [`:not()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) through the arbitrary variants. We'll pass the [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) and [`:last-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) psuedo-classes to the `:not()` pseudo-class as arguments, like so:

```
<div class="... [&>*:not(:first-child,:last-child)]:bg-white">
    <div class="flex w-full items-center justify-between gap-2 p-4"></div>
    <div class="flex flex-col gap-8 rounded-3xl border p-4"></div>
    <div class="flex flex-col gap-8 rounded-3xl border p-4"></div>
    <div class="flex flex-col gap-8 rounded-3xl border p-4"></div>
    <div class="flex h-10 gap-3 self-end p-4"></div>
</div>
```

This works similarly to the ["*:" modifier](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-direct-children) (which resolves to `& > *`), with the difference being the usage of `:not()`. Here is a [working example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/PFdVFqxE7W).

As a side note, while I personally find the capabilities of Tailwind and CSS amazing in displayed in the above code, if you are only styling a few divs differently than others, I would put the background color directly in the class list, solely to save my future self or others from confusion when I need to come back to the code.